# Boolean equation

Tags: c++, boolean-logic

Why this fragment of code has two different outputs (GCC 4.5.1) (I've commented important lines):

```
int main()
{
    bool a = 1;
    bool b = 1;
    bool c = 1;
    bool a_or_b = (a || b);
    bool not_a_or_b = !a_or_b;
    bool not_a_or_b__c = not_a_or_b || c;
    cout << "(a || b): " << (a || b) << '\n';
    cout << "!(a || b): " << !(a || b) << '\n';
    cout << "!(a || b) || c: " << (!(a || b)) || c << '\n';//HERE I'M GETTING 0 (incorrectly I would say)
    cout << "bool vars:\n";//WHY THIS LINE IS PRINTED AFTER THE PREVIOUS LINE BUT NOT BELOW IT?
    cout << "(a || b): " << a_or_b << '\n';
    cout << "!(a || b): " << not_a_or_b << '\n';
    cout << "!(a || b) || c: " << not_a_or_b__c << '\n';//HERE I'M GETTING 1
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because `<<` has higher precedence than `||`. Use parenthesis to group it.

```
cout << "!(a || b) || c: " << ((!(a || b)) || c) << '\n';
//                            ^                ^
```

Answer (score 4):

It interprets

```
(!(a || b)) || c << '\n'
```

as

```
(!(a || b)) || (c << '\n')
```

Comment: Actually it interprets as `( cout << ... << (!(a || b)) ) || (c << '\n')`

Comment: And of course, `(c << '\n')` is a legal expression: convert c to
and int, then shift it left 10 (the numeric value of '\n' on
almost all systems).

A good compiler would have perhaps warned that the results of
the expression (the top-most || expression) were never used.

Answer (score 2):

Change this part:

```
<< (!(a || b)) || c << '\n'; //interpreted as (!(a || b)) || (c << '\n')
```

to this:

```
((!(a || b)) || c) << '\n'; //interpreted as intended!
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Clamp Issue

u use (!(a || b)) || c the first part is 0 for sure perhaps the interpreter doesnt even watch the || c part.

Comment: For a logical OR, the compiled code (usually C++ isn't interpreted) must consider the second operand if the first operand is `false`. Only if the first operand is `true` must the second operand not be evaluated.